# When does SELECT query starts with a 'With'

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, odbc

I was reading this question [How to determine type of the sql query for jdbcTemplate in JAVA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671452/how-to-determine-type-of-the-sql-query-for-jdbctemplate-in-java). The correct answer says, a SELECT query can either start with a `SELECT` or a `WITH`.

Just for reference, the answer said:

```
// SELECT subqueries are irrelevant for the final result. So the command, the first verb is indicative of the result (int updateCount vs. ResultSet).

boolean isSqlSelect = sql.toUpperCase().startsWith("SELECT")
                   || sql.toUpperCase().startsWith("WITH");
```

So, now lets say I have a query

```
SELECT id, name, email FROM users;
```

**Questions**

1. How can I rewrite that query starting with a `WITH`?
2. And although the question was for JDBC, is it common for all SQL and ODBC/JDBC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`WITH` is the syntax for [common table expressions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) (CTEs).  This is standard SQL syntax supported basically by all reasonable databases (MySQL was the last to add such support).

CTEs are used to define subqueries that can be referenced multiple times in the query.

Note that CTEs can be used with `UPDATE` and `DELETE` statements as well as `SELECT`, so they do not necessarily indicate a `SELECT`.

Comment: So is it common to all DBs supporting sql?

Comment: @Chilarai I researched this and found that except for Informix, all major SQL implementations now support `WITH` syntax for CTE's (MySQL 8.0 was the last one to adopt it). https://stackoverflow.com/a/325243/20860

Comment: @Chilarai . . . Pretty much anything I would call a database.

Comment: Correction: Informix 14.10 added support for `WITH` in version 14.10, in 2019. I've updated the answer I linked to above.

Comment: @BillKarwin . . . That leaves out MS Access, which I am happy to leave out.

Comment: Oy! MS Access lacks _tons_ of standard SQL features. Don't even bother to list what's missing.

Answer (score 4):

Since you also asked how you could rewrite your query using CTE...

```
with cte as

(select id, name, email 
 from users)

select * from cte;
```

I find it cleaner to define column names early on in the `with` clause so I save some space for my `select`

```
with cte (id, name, email) as

(select *
 from users)

select * from cte;
```